# This is my code for recording video directly in Android,but it doesn't work.It shows a black color screen only.Anyone can help me please?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, video-recording

This is my code for recording video directly in Android. But it doesn't work, it shows only a black screen when running.

Permissions are:
 Write to external storage,Record Audio and Camera

MainActivity:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    stopRecording();
    super.onDestroy();
 }

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
private Camera mCamera;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Start");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Start")) {
        try {

            startRecording();
            item.setTitle("Stop");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            String message = e.getMessage();
            Log.i(null, "Problem " + message);
            mrec.release();
        }

    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Stop")) {
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
        mrec = null;
        item.setTitle("Start");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void startRecording() throws IOException {
    if (mCamera == null)
        mCamera = Camera.open();

    String filename;
    String path;

    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            .toString();

    Date date = new Date();
    filename = "/rec" + date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")
            + ".mp4";

    // create empty file it must use
    File file = new File(path, filename);

    mrec = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.lock();
    mCamera.unlock();

    // Please maintain sequence of following code.

    // If you change sequence it will not work.
    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mrec.setOutputFile(path + filename);
    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();

   }

  protected void stopRecording() {

    if (mrec != null) {
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera.lock();
    }
   }

private void releaseMediaRecorder() {

    if (mrec != null) {
        mrec.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
        mrec.release(); // release the recorder object
    }
  }






enter code here

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }



   }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (mCamera != null) {
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        Log.i("Surface", "Created");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        finish();
    }


    }

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();

}
}
```

This is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"`enter code here`
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Here in my Android Manifest file

```
package="com.example.videorecord"

android:versionCode="1"

android:versionName="1.0" >



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application 

    android : allowBackup="true"

    android:icon=  "@drawable /ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.videorecord.MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: have you defined camera permission in manifest?

Comment: yes, write external storage and record audio permissions are also added in manifest

Comment: also show your manifest file..

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the right permission set in AndroidManifest.xml

   `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
2. Check every step's result: surface created; recorder prepare/start ...
3. Try to set video frame rate and size.

   `mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(10);`
   `mRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);`

Gook luck.

Comment: I've copied your code into an empty project. And it works fine, I can see the camera preview in surfaceview. That's weird. My phone is Android 4.0.3. Maybe you should try another phone.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use MediaRecorder class.

Please have a look at this :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html